# Error : HDFS Not Ready (Data-torrent RTS sandbox)

Tags: apache-apex

I was trying Datatorrent sandbox but was getting this error ....

HDFS Not Ready
HDFS may still be starting up, or there may be other configuration issues with your hadoop services.

The console checks for changes in the status of these services every 10 seconds, but you can also trigger a refresh manually.

> Adding Env Details :
>
> OS : Ubuntu 14.04
>
> virtual box : virtualbox-5.0_5.0.18-106667
>
> datatorrent : datatorrent-sandbox-3.2.0

Comment: Can you check if hdfs and yarn are running? You can check the dtgateway.log in /var/log/datatorrent/ for hdfs related exceptions. Also ensure to have write permission for gateway user on the path you configured for DFS location on DT console.

Answer (score 2):

### Are you on a Mac by any chance ? Can you try restarting the services with a script like this (this script just checks the status; you can replace *status* with *stop* or *start* or *restart*):

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to check status of various Hadoop services

# NOTE: If machine was shutdown improperly, or if HDFS continues to show red
# not-ready status, some of these may not be running; just start them if needed with:
#    sudo service <name> start
# where <name> is the name of the service you want to start
#
services="hadoop-hdfs-namenode hadoop-hdfs-datanode hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager \
hadoop-yarn-nodemanager dtdemos"
for s in $services; do
    sudo service $s status
done

# gateway service
sudo service dtgateway status
```

---

If that doesn't work either, try these commands to force it out of safe mode:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
hdfs fsck -delete
```

Comment: I tried this no effect ... Service restarted successfully .. but with same error

Comment: On the sandbox at /var/log/datatorrent/dtgateway.log

Comment: (Ignore previous comment, hit enter too soon) On the sandbox at `/sfw/hadoop/shared/logs` there are files: `hadoop-dtadmin-datanode-dtbox.log`, `hadoop-dtadmin-namenode-dtbox.log`, and `yarn-dtadmin-nodemanager-dtbox.log`. Could you look through those and paste any exceptions here ?

Answer (score 1):

HDFS will be in a safe mode for few seconds just after the start up.
Read more about it here:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode

Answer (score 0):

Can you check dtgateway.log file for any more specific details? The file is usually located at `/home/username/.dt/logs/dtgateway.log`.